# Django-Virtual env

Tags: python, django, web-frameworks

scripts folder is not available in my virtual environment folder.Any one please help me
How to activate virtual env ?

I did following commonds :-

> > > pip3 install virtualenv

> > > virtualenv bg
> > > cd bg

> > > cd scripts

shailesh@shailesh:~/Blog/bg$ cd scripts
bash: cd: scripts: No such file or directory
shailesh@shailesh:~/Blog/bg$

Answer (score 0):

You use an virtualenv like this:

### Windows:

```
virtualenv my-env
myenv/scripts/activate
```

### On MacOS:

```
virtualenv my-env
source venv/bin/activate
```

Here is the first line the creation with the name `my-env` and the scond line the activation. [Here is another resource you can take a look at.](https://bodo-schoenfeld.de/eine-virtuelle-umgebung-fuer-python-erstellen/)

Comment: The path should be
```Users\User\Envs\your-env\Scripts```